# How can I fix the ValueError at /add invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, html, django

Hi I can't figure out how to stop getting this error when is click on submit.

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'name':'Noah'})

def add(request):

  val1 = int(request.POST ['num1'])
  val2 = int(request.POST ['num2'])
  res = val1+val2

  return render(request, 'result.html', {'result':res})
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<h1>hello {{name}}!!!!</h1>

<form action="add" method="POST">

  {% csrf_token %}

  Enter 1st number: <input type="text" name="num1">
  Enter 2nd number: <input type="text" name="num2">
  <input type="submit">
</form>

{% endblock %}
```

my result.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

Result : {{result}}

{% endblock %}
```

Please help I've been following a tutorial and can't figure out why I can't solve this error.

Comment: It looks like you did not pass two numbers in your form?

Comment: I'm so stupid thank you